# concatenate flatten output with and other datasets keras python

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, convolution

have 2 datasets, for the first data set i want to apply  convolution and keep the result of flatten layyer then concatenate it with an other data set and a do a simple feed forward it is possible with keras ?

```
def build_model(x_train,y_train):
    np.random.seed(7)

    left = Sequential()

    left.add(Conv1D(nb_filter= 6, filter_length=3, input_shape= (48,1),activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    left.add(Conv1D(nb_filter= 6,  filter_length=3, activation= 'relu'))
    #model.add(MaxPooling1D())
    print model
    #model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    # flatten layer 
    #https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-flattening-step-in-a-convolutional-neural-network
    left.add(Flatten())


    left.add(Reshape((48,1)))
    right = Sequential()

    #model.add(Reshape((48,1)))
# Compile model

    model.add(Merge([left, right], mode='sum'))
    model.add(Dense(10, 10))
    epochs = 100
    lrate = 0.01
    decay = lrate/epochs
    sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=False)
              #clipvalue=0.5)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam')
    model.fit(x_train,y_train, nb_epoch =epochs, batch_size=10, verbose=1)

    #model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'] , )

    return model
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Does the code you posted work or not? What would you want it to do differently?

Comment: my code does not working i have 2 datasets but with the same target for the the first dataset i want to apply a convolution and keep the flatten output then concatenate it w with the second datasets and do a simple feedforwad

Comment: Where exactly does it break?

Comment: it does not break but i don"t know what should i do  in model.fit(x_train,y_train, nb_epoch =epochs, batch_size=10, verbose=1) how can i concatenate the output flatten with and other output how my keras model wil know the datasets used with flatten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).  The sequential model you are using is not designed to take multiple network inputs.
Follow the "Multi-input and multi-output models" example and you will have it working in no time!